Remove duplicate object in XSLT using Saxon streaming
I need help removing duplicate items from the feed and mapping the first object. For that I am using xsl:for-each-group to group the object by id and using it.
It works fine with small XML But when I use a large feed that contains 2 Million items, it does not perform xsl transform, the file is empty.
Is there any other way I can achieve the same without using the grouping?
I am using saxon ee 10.5 version
xsl template
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dq" select="'&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="qcq" select="'&quot;,&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lf" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <!-- Static defaults -->
    <xsl:variable name="data_source" select="'HHTestMedia'"/>   
    <xsl:template match="items">
        <xsl:text>title,city,state,postal_code,country,company_name</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
                        <!--<xsl:for-each select="job ! copy-of(.)">-->
                <xsl:for-each-group select="item ! copy-of(.)" group-by="id">
                    <xsl:variable name="currentGroup" select="current-group()[1]"/>                    
                    <xsl:variable name="p_title" select="substring($currentGroup/replace(title,'&quot;',''),0,128)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="p_city" select="substring-before($currentGroup/location,',')"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="p_state_code" select="substring(normalize-space(substring-after($currentGroup/location,',')),1,2)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="p_postal_code" select="$currentGroup/postcode"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="p_country_code" select="$currentGroup/country"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="p_company_name" select="replace(substring($currentGroup/company,1,64),'&quot;','')"/>                                       
                    <!-- The following line should not need to be updated if you copied this XSL from a different setup. -->
                    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat($dq,$p_title,$qcq,$p_city,$qcq,$p_state_code,$qcq,$p_postal_code,$qcq,$p_country_code,$qcq,$p_company_name,$dq,$lf)"/>
                    <!--</xsl:for-each>-->
                </xsl:for-each-group>           
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>



sample XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<source>

<items>
  <item>
    <id><![CDATA[160449417]]></id>
    <title><![CDATA[Campaign1]]></title>
        <location><![CDATA[Hudson, FL 34667]]></location>
      <postcode><![CDATA[34667]]></postcode>
      <country><![CDATA[US]]></country>
    <company><![CDATA[Halloween]]></company>    
    </item>
  <item>
    <id><![CDATA[160449417]]></id>
    <title><![CDATA[Campaign1]]></title>
        <location><![CDATA[Hudson, FL 34667]]></location>
      <postcode><![CDATA[34667]]></postcode>
      <country><![CDATA[US]]></country>
    <company><![CDATA[Halloween]]></company>    
    </item>
  </items>
  </source>

Thanks in advance.

Do you get any error or warning from Saxon? How do you run the transformation, from the command line with -o, and then the result file is empty? Can you add -t to see some timing information? Or do you run with Java code (or C# code)? Can you show the code? It seems odd that you don't get any error but an empty file.

You've shown a trivial example, but in your example, the duplicates are adjacent to each other. If that is always going to be the case, then you can exploit the fact by using group-adjacent, which will need much less memory.

@Gopinath, could you solve your problem with the posted answers?

We should try to run some diagnostics to identify why your approach fails.
But as you also asked for an alternative way, without using grouping, here is one using an accumulator that stores the processed item/id counts in a map(xs:integer, xs:integer):
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    version="3.0">
  
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" use-accumulators="processed-ids"/>
    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="dq" select="'&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="qcq" select="'&quot;,&quot;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="lf" select="'&#10;'"/>
    <!-- Static defaults -->
    <xsl:variable name="data_source" select="'HHTestMedia'"/>   
    
    <xsl:accumulator name="processed-ids" as="map(xs:integer, xs:integer)" initial-value="map{}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="items/item/id/text()"
        select="let $id := xs:integer(.),
                    $already-processed := map:contains($value, $id)
                return 
                  if ($already-processed)
                  then map:put($value, $id, $value($id) + 1) 
                  else map:put($value, $id, 1)"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    
    <xsl:template match="items">
        <xsl:text>title,city,state,postal_code,country,company_name</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="items/item">
      <xsl:variable name="item" select="copy-of()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="id" select="xs:integer($item/id)"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$item[accumulator-after('processed-ids')($id) = 1]" mode="grounded"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:mode name="grounded"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="item" mode="grounded">
      <xsl:variable name="currentGroup" select="."/>                    
      <xsl:variable name="p_title" select="substring($currentGroup/replace(title,'&quot;',''),0,128)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="p_city" select="substring-before($currentGroup/location,',')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="p_state_code" select="substring(normalize-space(substring-after($currentGroup/location,',')),1,2)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="p_postal_code" select="$currentGroup/postcode"/>
      <xsl:variable name="p_country_code" select="$currentGroup/country"/>
      <xsl:variable name="p_company_name" select="replace(substring($currentGroup/company,1,64),'&quot;','')"/>                                       

      <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat($dq,$p_title,$qcq,$p_city,$qcq,$p_state_code,$qcq,$p_postal_code,$qcq,$p_country_code,$qcq,$p_company_name,$dq,$lf)"/>      
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>


Thanks, Martin and Michael Kay for the response. I am still getting empty files with the accumulator approach. I am using JRuby with java saxon libraries. I will try to run my code in locally and diagnose it. I will update you once I have some details.

You are copying every item in the input using <xsl:for-each-group select="item ! copy-of(.)" group-by="id"> so although you're streaming the input, you still need enough working memory to hold the entire document. Theoretically, however, you only need enough working memory to hold the id values. If you want to output the first item with a given id and discard the remainder, then saving the remainder in memory is a waste of space. Martin has suggested a good way of avoiding this overhead by using accumulators. Another way would be to use xsl:iterate, something like
<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:iterate select="item ! copy-of()">
    <xsl:param name="id-values" select="map{}"/>
    <xsl:if test="not(map:contains($id-values, id))">
      <!-- output this item, then ... -->
      <xsl:next-iteration>
        <xsl:with-param name="id-values" 
                        select="map:put($id-values, id, true())"/>
      </xsl:next-iteration>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:iterate>
</xsl:template> 

